# Google Tag Manager and Google Analytics Conversion

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, google-tag-manager

Anyone had the problem whereby the Transaction number is the only thing wrong in GA Conversion results, through GTM?

The firing rules to include only Thank you (receipt) page seems to be ignored.

Other values in conversion such as Qty and Unique purchases are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change include Rules to block rules and it works now.

Not sure why the Inlude rules were not followed.

**So for example:**

Instead of *Firing* rule when (page is thank you page)

I had *Blocking* rule when (page is not thank you page)